# Как настроить ширину кнопки с изображением в tkinter на python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Код:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

image = tk.PhotoImage(file = "image.png")
button = ttk.Button(root, image = image)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Неудачные попытки увеличить ширину кнопки:

1. Указать width.
2. Указать padx.
3. Указать text как несколько пробелов.

Кнопка нужна именно из ttk. Как изменить ширину кнопки с изображением?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582387/image-resize-under-photoimage

Comment: https://fooobar.com/questions/13100727/tkinter-button-resize

Comment: Интик, это не работает на кнопку.

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл решение. Буду использовать фрейм как родитель кнопке, у которой будет pack(fill = tk.BOTH). А размеры кнопки будут регулировать размерами родителя.

UPD: На root кнопка изменяет размер, но при Frame она не учитывает размеры родителя. Вопрос ещё не решён.

UPD: После поиска возможных решений работающим оказалось одно - изменение файла изображения с добавлением пустоты по краям.

UPD: Решение найдено! В метод place можно передать параметры width и height в пикселях. Кнопка с изображением охотно меняет размеры. Наконец, вопрос закрыт.

Answer (score 0):

Первое решение которое приходит в голову, просто расширить картинку (*например, с помощью Photoshop, там можно убрать белый фон и останется фон прозрачный*), таким образом можно настраивать и длину, и высоту кнопки, а её размер (*если работать в фотошопе*) будет определятся размерами документа. Если найду решение кодом, вам напишу.

Comment: Похоже, придёться менять изображение добавлением прозрачных областей. Других вариантов не нашёл.

Comment: Я пока всё ещё ищу решение с помощью кода, не теряйте надежду!

Comment: Хорошо, буду ждать)

Comment: А кстати, можете дать идею, может можно справится без Frame?

Comment: Теоретически, если у ttk.Button найти свойство, подобное padx у tk.Button, то можно и без Frame. Или же, если tk.Button получится стилизовать также, как ttk.Button.

Comment: Все ещё ищете? Вы уверены, что хотите продолжать?

Comment: Извините, я отходил, но ничего не нашёл. Думаю, может как-то поставить картинки или гифку на tk.Button, чтобы выглядело как ttk.Button.

Comment: Можете не заморачиваться, я уже использую изменённые изображения. И все же спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Не знаю, пришло ли вам уведомление об изменении ответа, но я нашёл решение!